# django style a form with jquery

Tags: jquery, django, forms, hide

I am trying to "style" a django form using jquery. Now i just started with jquery.
What I want to do is cut the form into subgroups, and extend on click or depending on a choice you made in the form. (do i need ajax for this?)

For now i try to "hide" elements with a css class, and remove or add that class when needed.

html:

```
<form action="{% url 'item_create' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ item_form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

css:

```
.hide {display: none;}
```

js:

```
$(function(){
  $('#id_flavor').addClass('hide');
});
```

where #id_flavor is the id for the flavor field in my form. My problem now is that it only hides the input field, and not my label and help_text.
How can i achieve that it removes field+extra field parts

(a part of my rendered django form http://pastebin.com/LtKFUJaT (not sure if it helps as extra information)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jquery you could just do something like this to hide whole input container:

```
$(function() {
  $('#id_flavor').parents('p:first').hide();
});
```